# In proguard, how to preserve a set of classes' method names?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am using proguard to obfuscate my android application.  The android application contains some native code, which makes callbacks to fully qualified java methods.  I need to not obfuscate these classes and the names of their methods.  The below properly keeps the class names, but not the method names.

```
-keep public class com.me.dontobf.*
-keepnames public class com.me.dontobf.*
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For native methods: [ProGuard manual > Examples > Processing native methods](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#native)

```
# note that <methods> means any method
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

In this case, for callback methods: [ProGuard manual > Examples > Processing callback methods](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#callback)

```
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
    void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
}
```

Or e.g., if all public methods may be callback methods:

```
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
    public <methods>;
}
```

You probably also need to keep any program classes that occur in the method descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

From the ProGuard manual: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work for me.  I need to preserve method names of non-native methods which are called from native code. Your suggestion keeps class names of classes that contain native methods.