# Keeping a method with single parameter using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I have one method

```
public class XYZ {
    public void foo(boolean isAvailable) {

    }
}
```

I am using Proguard to obfuscate, Please let me know how can I keep the method foo with it's boolean parameter.

Comment: Did you applied any proguard rule yet, such as "keep" ? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880107/in-proguard-how-to-preserve-a-set-of-classes-method-names

Comment: I am keeping the class, and keeping some specific methods into it.

Comment: -keepclasseswithmembernames class YourClassName {
    <methods>;
}  // something along these lines should do

Comment: Problem is that I can keep the parameter names for methods, where the parameters are of reference type. 
But I can't keep the primitive parameter.

Comment: -keepclasseswithmembernames class YourClassName { <methods>; } will keep all the methods, 
But I want a specific method only which have single boolean param

Comment: annotate the method with @Keep

Comment: @Keep is keeping the method but not it's parameter name.

void xyz(boolean abc), here it is keeping the method xyz but obfuscating abc to b.

The method name name I can already keep with my current changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
-keepparameternames

-keep class com.abc.XYZ {
    public void foo(boolean);
}
```

`-keepparameternames` will not obfuscate the method parameters

Comment: parameter name is still obfuscated. I want to keep the parameter name.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This works,  but concerned, 

keepparameternames will keep parameters for all the method in class ?

Comment: As only want to keep the param for method foo(boolean);

Comment: Yes, for all methods that you mentioned